# Can you turn a Unreal Project .EXE into .uproject?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have a .exe file, called Sonic Infinity Engine Plus, that was built in UE4.
This was released public without source code download, so I am unable to modify it. 
However, this game was released with an Unreal terminal (accessed by the `/~ key). I'm wondering if there is any way I could retrieve the source code.

[Image of terminal in-game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENjWv.png)

If anybody knows such command, like `build source`, it would be helpful to know.

 If you need more information I couldn't think of off the top of my head, please let me know!

Thanks, Omega207

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. The field of decompiling and reverse engineering is big and complicated, but the fact that the compilation included an unreal console terminal does not mean the source code is in there somewhere.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I kinda figured. Though it is weird, given that this is a engine, and the terminal isn't the only instance of Unreal (reminders of needing built light, etc.).

Comment: It would be weird if this *were* possible.

Answer (score 0):

As user Rotem replied, there is no known way to retrieve the "source code" as I thought it could. This is due to complications with decompiling UE4 source code.
This is due to the fact that Unreal tends to hide source to most who use it, and is therefor up to the creators to distribute source code (which is all the files creating the .exe file).

Since the source was never distributed public, there is officially no possible way to modify this engine as the creators meant it to be.

Comment: Your analysis and understanding of this problem is flawed.  It is not even an issue with "decompiling" UE4 specifically - decompiling is a reverse engineering technique, not a code recovery technique - moreover it is mostly a myth and works only in very limited circumstances and to a very limited extent. It is not an issue that can be "fixed".  It is fundamental to compiled code.  The source code is used to generate machine code.  The machine code does not somehow "contain" the original source, and for the most part the source cannot be inferred from the machine code.

Comment: ... That would be like trying to create flour, water, yeast, a recipe and the energy used to cook it from a loaf of bread.  All of it is changed, and some of it is no longer present.  Moreover if the copyright owner does not allow you to have the copyright material, that is their prerogative.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Yeah, I understand the problems of this question, and I feel very silly for asking. The only reason I asked was because I was desperate to find a solution to my problem. I am truly sorry for anything I have asked here, and I ask that you please understand this misunderstanding.

Comment: I am not very experienced with Unreal Engine, nor its flaws and solutions. And I do understand that having no source code means that this project wasn't meant to be manipulated. However, this IS a engine, and this was distributed on a software hosting site, and descriptions made it very clear that this engine was supposed to be modified.